# How to give the user the ability to scroll after a restricted functions to auto scroll down

Tags: javascript, scroll, modal-dialog, scrollbar, autoscroll

I'm making a basic chat web, I used some predefined classes from bootstraps for my modal forms as the chat forms combined with some CSS of my own, the issue is that every time the user will open the chat form modal, the output inside the form(which is having a CSS attribute of overflow: scroll;) that displays messages always start showing the oldest message, and the user have to scroll down to display the latest message, I figured out a script from one of the questions here that make the output displays the latest message, but now I cannot scroll to top any more :)

here is the script for 3 forms outputs

```js
   

 <script>
    
    const messages0 = document.getElementById('output0');
    const messages1 = document.getElementById('output1');
    const messages2 = document.getElementById('output2');
    
    function getMessages() {
        // Prior to getting your messages.
      shouldScroll0 = messages0.scrollTop + messages0.clientHeight === messages0.scrollHeight;
      shouldScroll1 = messages1.scrollTop + messages1.clientHeight === messages1.scrollHeight;
      shouldScroll2 = messages2.scrollTop + messages2.clientHeight === messages2.scrollHeight;
      
      // After getting your messages.
      if (!shouldScroll0) {
        scrollToBottom(messages0);
       
      }
      if (!shouldScroll1) {
        scrollToBottom(messages1);
      }
      if (!shouldScroll2) {
        scrollToBottom(messages2);
      }
    
    }
    
    function scrollToBottom() {
      messages0.scrollTop = messages0.scrollHeight;
      messages1.scrollTop = messages1.scrollHeight;
      messages2.scrollTop = messages2.scrollHeight;
    }
    
    scrollToBottom();
    
    setInterval(getMessages, 100);
    </script>
```

```css
*here is the CSS of the output and variables inside of it 


<style>
.message-blue {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #A8DDFD;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font: 400 .9em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #97C6E3;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.message-orange {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: calc(100% - 240px);
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f8e896;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font: 400 .9em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #dfd087;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.message-content {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.message-timestamp-right {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 300;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}

.message-timestamp-left {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: 300;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}

.message-blue:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #A8DDFD;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: -15px;
}

.message-blue:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 17px solid #97C6E3;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    top: -1px;
    left: -17px;
}

.message-orange:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #f8e896;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -15px;
}

.message-orange:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 17px solid #dfd087;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -17px;
}
.output{
      border: 2px solid gray;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: scroll;
  
    height: 250px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
and here is the HTML of 1 modal form output


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home page chat application</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="output0" class="output">
        <?php
---some php related to the db insertion of new messages----
?>
<?php 
include ("ConfigFile.php");
$name=$_SESSION["user"];
$seqo = "SELECT * FROM `adminposts` WHERE `Group_by` = 'Admin' AND `admin_id`='606' or `Group_by` = '606E'";
$resu=$link->query($seqo);

if ($resu->num_rows != 0){

  while($row = $resu->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row["Group_by"]=='Admin'){
      
      echo "<h3 style='color:red;'>".$row["name"]." --".$row["date"]." "."<br> :<div id='messagess'>".$row["msg"]."</div><br> *Announcement* <br> </h3>";}
  
      if($row["name"]=="$name"){
        echo "<div class='message-blue'>";
        echo "<h4>".$row["name"]."</h4>";
        echo "<div class = 'message-content' id='messagess'>".$row["msg"]."</div> <br>";
        echo "<div class='message-timestamp-left'>".$row["date"]."</div>";
        echo "</div>";}

      if($row["Group_by"] !== 'Admin' && $row["name"]!=="$name") { echo "<div class='message-orange'>";
        echo "<h4>".$row["name"]."</h4>";
        echo "<p class = 'message-content'>".$row["msg"]."</p> <br>";
        echo "<div class='message-timestamp-right'>".$row["date"]."</div>";
        echo "</div>";}
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "no messages were displayed yet.";
    }
    $link->close();
    ?>
    </div>
   
          </div>

</body>
```

pls, help :') probably an if statement within the script will give the user the option to scroll, and that only if the user submits a message or user opens the modal, then the output will auto display the latest of the output without scrolling

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out as i said, a small if/else statement will do the trick, and i tested few options and this worked with me :

```
else {
$("#output2 #output1 #output0").on('scroll', function(){
scrollToBottom=false;});}
```

which is added to the if statements of (!shouldScroll)

so the total script should be like this :

```js
<script>

const messages0 = document.getElementById('output0');
const messages1 = document.getElementById('output1');
const messages2 = document.getElementById('output2');

function getMessages() {
    // Prior to getting your messages.
  shouldScroll0 = messages0.scrollTop + messages0.clientHeight === messages0.scrollHeight;
  shouldScroll1 = messages1.scrollTop + messages1.clientHeight === messages1.scrollHeight;
  shouldScroll2 = messages2.scrollTop + messages2.clientHeight === messages2.scrollHeight;
  
  // After getting your messages.
  if (!shouldScroll0) {
    scrollToBottom(messages0.scrollTop);
   
  }
  
  if (!shouldScroll1) {
    scrollToBottom(messages1.scrollTop);
  }
  
   
  if (!shouldScroll2) {
    scrollToBottom(messages2.scrollTop);
  }
  else {
    $("#output2 #output1 #output0").on('scroll', function(){
    scrollToBottom=false;
});
  }

}

function scrollToBottom() {
 messages0.scrollTop = messages0.scrollHeight;
  messages1.scrollTop = messages1.scrollHeight;
  messages2.scrollTop = messages2.scrollHeight;
}

scrollToBottom();

setInterval(getMessages, 100);

</script>
```

in this way, when the user opens up the chat form, it will auto show the latest message, also after submitting a message, it will show also the latest message, but if the user will scroll to the top, it will be allowed